# Send New-WebServiceProxy SOAP request to multiple endpoints

Tags: powershell, soap, new-webserviceproxy

first ever time with PS, first ever time scripting in general!

I have a wsdl stored locally on my host machine, which points to a localhost endpoint. This is necessary, as the remote servers do not serve the wsdl. They are, however, valid endpoints for these SOAP requests.

I have multiple endpoints across my network, and i want to send the New-WebServiceProxy request to each one whilst referencing the static wsdl. Is there a way to use the local wsdl, but specify a target endpoint override?

This is what I currently have (excuse the comments, i'm trying to learn):

```
# The uri refers to the wsdl page            

$uri = ( Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "\wsdl\PublicService.wsdl" )

# Create the Web Service Proxy           
$service = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri  -Namespace WebServiceProxy  -UseDefaultCredential -Verbose       

# Specify the list of target servers IP addressesr hostnames

$serverlistpath = ( Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "\servers\servers.txt" )
$servers = gc $serverlistpath


# Create an output path to the templates folderr use witin the SOAP request
$templatetemp = ( Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "\template_temp\" )


# Gets the UNC path of the script running location

$currentDirectory = Get-Location
$currentDrive = Split-Path -qualifier $currentDirectory.Path
$logicalDisk = Gwmi Win32_LogicalDisk -filter "DriveType = 4 AND DeviceID = '$currentDrive'"
$uncPath = $currentDirectory.Path.Replace($currentDrive, $logicalDisk.ProviderName)

# Execute SOAP request

$service.Backup("false", "true", "false", "false", "$uncpath\template_temp")
```

I plan to run this as a ForEach loop for each server in servers.txt, but need to be able to set a different URL each time whilst pointing to the static wsdl. Each server does not serve the wsdl itself.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at creating a CSV file with two headers, one for your server names and the other for the URL.

Ex.

`server,url
SERVER01,http://www.example.com/oneendpoint
SERVER02,http://www.example.com/twoendpoint`

Then you can iterate over each entry using a foreach loop. You can import csv files easily in PowerShell with the `Import-CSV` cmdlet

Comment: Thanks for this response, it is appreciated.

However, I am still confused, as even if I used a CSV with two headers, the New-WebServiceProxy would still reference the endpoint stipulated in the local wsdl. I am looking for a way to override the endpoint that is coded in the WSDL, as none of my servers will serve the wsdl live.